# How must be write adress to api controller and with attribute in controller. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have api controller with only one method for Get data. But I want to include there my api method, Delete and Edit.I realized it in other controller and it work such simple method. And I put it on my api controller. When I put the attribute `[HttpDelete]` I have wrong address, but in page form I did write tag for method "delete"

This code is not working. The route for address on controller:`[Route("api/BlogApi")]`

```
 <form asp-action="DeletePostFromDB" asp-route="api/BlogApi" asp-controller="Home" method="delete" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How I must make page with form with right tag and attribute for method "delete", "edit", "get"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1#call-the-web-api-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

In html  the supported methods are get and post
Have a look:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

For method delete ([HttpDelete]) you'll have to use ajax or smth.

If you want to use  you can make DeletePostFromDB as [HttpGet]/[HttpPost].

Btw I think asp-route="api/BlogApi" is not needed - you have asp-controller.